# Implementing a temporary exclusive relationship between two objects

Tags: c#, oop

I need to implement a relationship between two objects Owner and Item such that an owner owns 0..1 items and each item can only be owned by a single owner at one time.

The class definitions are as follow:

```cs
class Item
{
}

class Owner
{
   public Item item { get; set; }
}
```

The point is that when an owner has an item assigned to it, any other owner loses its ownership of the item (and its item reference is set to null).

See this example code:

```cs
Owner owner1 = new Owner();
Owner owner2 = new Owner();
Item anItem = new Item();
// right now owner1.item and owner2.item are both null

owner1.item = anItem;
// owner1.item is anItem and owner2.item is null

owner2.item = anItem;
// owner1.item is null and owner2.item is anItem
```

What would be an efficient and correct way to implement this behaviour?

I'm sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology, perhaps due to the lack of my knowledge of it I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Do you have a Database? Or is it a code without a database ?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the setter. You might need an `Owner` property in the `Item` class :

In class `Item` :

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Owner owner = null;
    public Owner Owner
    {
        get { return owner; }
        set
        {
            owner = value;
            Console.WriteLine($"I am {Name} and I am now owned by {(owner != null ? owner.Name : "no one")}");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we can do the same in the `Owner` class :

```
class Owner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Item item = null;
    public Item Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                value.Owner = this;
            }
            item = value;
            Console.WriteLine($"I am {Name} and I now own {(item != null ? item.Name : "no one")}");
        }
    }
}
```

***But this just sets the relation in a double direction ! This doesn't remove the ownership of another object !***

Right, but now we can use `item.Owner` to remove the relation between the old owner and the item, such as :

```
class Owner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Item item = null;
    public Item Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.Owner != null)
                {
                    value.Owner.Item = null;
                }
                value.Owner = this;
            }
            item = value;
            Console.WriteLine($"I am {Name} and I now own {(item != null ? item.Name : "no one")}");
        }
    }
}
```

***But what if I want to use*** `owner.Item = null` ***the item need to have its owner removed too !***

Right, we can use the `item.Owner` to remove the relation if value is `null`

```
class Owner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Item item = null;
    public Item Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.Owner != null)
                {
                    value.Owner.Item = null;
                }
                value.Owner = this;
            }
            else
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.Owner = null;
                }
            }

            item = value;
            Console.WriteLine($"I am {Name} and I now own {(item != null ? item.Name : "no one")}");
        }
    }
}
```

We can now test it :

```
Owner owner1 = new Owner { Name = "owner1" };
Owner owner2 = new Owner { Name = "owner2" };
Item anItem = new Item { Name = "item1" };

owner1.Item = anItem;
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
owner2.Item = anItem;
```

**Output**

```
I am item1 and I am now owned by owner1
I am owner1 and I now own item1
---------------------------------
I am item1 and I am now owned by no one
I am owner1 and I now own no one
I am item1 and I am now owned by owner2
I am owner2 and I now own item1
```

Answer (score 0):

> The point is that when an owner has an item assigned to it, any other owner loses its ownership of the item (and its item reference is set to null).

The easiest way to achieve that is to invert the relationship (i.e. who stores the reference to the other)

```
public Item
{ 
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}
```

*You can also use `Owner.Id` or a similarly valid identifier, but the answer remains the same.*

This way, every item only has one "box" to register the owner in. Any registration that happens effectively overwrites the pre-existing owner, which is what you want.

Of course, since you want the relationship to be mostly symmetrical, you can achieve the same thing by having the reference in the `Owner` class. Which way you do it doesn't matter as much, use the one that makes the most sense to you (do you assign items to owners, or do you assign owners to items? It's a semantical difference, not a technical one)

> I need to implement a relationship between two objects Owner and Item such that an owner owns 0..1 items and each item can only be owned by a single owner at one time.

This isn't as simple to fix anymore, because you can't automate this behavior if you want this logic to apply on both sides of the relation.

To uphold the uniqueness (albeit nullable or not) on both ends of the relationship, you're going to have to use explicit business logic to confirm that the uniqueness is being upheld.

There isn't really a trick to it. It becomes a matter of forcing this check whenever someone wants to add a new Owner-Item relationship. One such example could be:

```
public class Item
{
    public Owner Owner { get; private set }

    public void SetOwner(Owner owner)
    {
        if(!owner.OwnsItem)
        {
            this.Owner = owner;
        }
        else
        {
            //Do nothing, throw an exception, log a message, ...
        }
    }
}

public class Owner
{
    public bool OwnsItem()
    {
        return ListOfAllItems.Any(item => item.Owner == this);
    }
}
```

Notes

- I have skipped over how you do an equality check for owners. Most likely, you'd check an ID value, but your question did not make that clear. Use whatever equality check is appropriate.
- I have also skipped over a null check for the `owner` parameter. It's unclear whether an item ever gets disowned or not. Add it if it is relevant to your case.
- This requires you having access to a list of all items so you can look for ownership. How you get that list very much depends on how you are storing your data, which you don't mention in your question. For the purpose of example, I assume `ListOfAllItems` gives you exactly what it says.

  - The `OwnsItem()` logic doesn't *have* to be in the `Owner` class if you don't want it to be. It makes sense there from a DDD perspective but you can just as well put it in a separate validation object or repository. It all depends on your architecture and your question doesn't reveal enough for me to conclusively answer that.
- If you want to be clever and give both classes a reference to each other, watch out for infinite recursion when each item tries to update its referenced item's property. It can be done, but I advise avoiding it where possible for two reasons:

  - It cuts down on the data handling you have to do.
  - It prevents the possibility of your data being inconsistent or contradicting itself (e.g. an owner who refers to an item which refers to a different owner)